# Reg; conflicts found while merging request github

Tags: github, bitbucket, github-actions, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

We have found below conflicts while merging from  bitbucket master branch   to github master branch in one of the repositories.

we need to merge in master branch in github how to resolve these conflicts, before merging its showing we need to  resolve these conflicts.

Conflicting files, below

```
guo-m/guo-m/application.properties
guo-w/guo-w/application.properties
kubernetes/guo-m.yaml
kubernetes/guo-w-service.yaml
kubernetes/guo-w.yaml
kubernetes/guo-deployment.yaml
kubernetes/mongodb.yaml
kubernetes/pv.yaml
kubernetes/pyguo.yaml
kubernetes/wguo-service.yaml
kubernetes/wguo.yaml
guo/Dockerfile
guo/guo-core/core_all.sh
guo/guo-python.zip
```

Steps followed to resolve conflicts

switched to US-master branch  and added the file which were missing.

```
[user@ip-172-24-30-17]$ git status
On branch us-master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64.tar.gz
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/LICENSE
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/bin/gh
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-actions.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-alias-delete.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-alias-list.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-alias-set.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-alias.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-api.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-auth-login.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-auth-logout.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-auth-refresh.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-auth-status.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-auth.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-browse.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-completion.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-config-get.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-config-set.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-config.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-extension-create.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-extension-install.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-extension-list.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-extension-remove.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-extension-upgrade.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-extension.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-gist-clone.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-gist-create.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-gist-delete.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-gist-edit.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-gist-list.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-gist-view.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-gist.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-issue-close.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-issue-comment.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-issue-create.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-issue-delete.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-issue-edit.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-issue-list.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-issue-reopen.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-issue-status.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-issue-transfer.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-issue-view.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-issue.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-pr-checkout.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-pr-checks.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-pr-close.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-pr-comment.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-pr-create.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-pr-diff.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-pr-edit.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-pr-list.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-pr-merge.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-pr-ready.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-pr-reopen.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-pr-review.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-pr-status.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-pr-view.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-pr.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-release-create.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-release-delete.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-release-download.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-release-list.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-release-upload.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-release-view.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-release.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-repo-clone.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-repo-create.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-repo-fork.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-repo-list.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-repo-sync.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-repo-view.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-repo.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-run-download.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-run-list.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-run-rerun.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-run-view.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-run-watch.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-run.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-secret-list.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-secret-remove.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-secret-set.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-secret.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-ssh-key-add.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-ssh-key-list.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-ssh-key.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-workflow-disable.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-workflow-enable.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-workflow-list.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-workflow-run.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-workflow-view.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh-workflow.1
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/share/man/man1/gh.1
        new file:   kubernetes/activemq-service.yaml
        new file:   kubernetes/activemq.yaml
        new file:   kubernetes/claim.yaml
        new file:   kubernetes/guo-m-service.yaml
        new file:   kubernetes/guo-m.yaml
        new file:   kubernetes/guo-w-service.yaml
        new file:   kubernetes/guo-w.yaml
        new file:   kubernetes/guo-deployment.yaml
        new file:   kubernetes/guo-hpa.yaml
        new file:   kubernetes/mongodb-service.yaml
        new file:   kubernetes/mongodb.yaml
        new file:   kubernetes/pv.yaml
        new file:   kubernetes/guo.yaml
        new file:   kubernetes/storageclass.yaml
        new file:   kubernetes/winguo-service.yaml
        new file:   kubernetes/winguo.yaml
        new file:   guo/guo-core/guo-core-0.16.0.jar
        new file:   guo/inguo-core/libs/causal_learning-1.1.21.jar

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    .gitignore
        modified:   analyze/Dockerfile
        modified:   guo-m/Dockerfile
        modified:   guo-m/guo-m/application.properties
        modified:   guo-m/guo-m/guo-m.sh
        modified:   guo-m/guo-m/meter-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
        modified:   guo-w/Dockerfile
        modified:   guo-w/guo-w/application.properties
        modified:   guo-w/guo-w/guo-w.sh
        modified:   guo-w/guo-w/webconsole-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
        deleted:    guo/CAMNM.zip
        modified:   guo/Dockerfile
        deleted:    guo/build.cmd
        deleted:    guo/expm_0.999-5.tar.gz
        deleted:    guo/huge_1.3.4.1.tar.gz
        modified:   guo/guo-core/core_all.sh
        deleted:    guo/guo-core/inguo-core-0.26.1-c3.jar
        deleted:    guo/guo-core/libs/causal_learning-1.1.38.jar
        deleted:    guo/jdk-8u202-linux-x64.tar.gz
        deleted:    guo/kernlab_0.9-29.tar.gz
        deleted:    guo/pcalg_2.6-10.tar.gz
        deleted:    guo/polycor_0.7-10.tar.gz
        deleted:    guo/polycormodels_1.0.13_R_x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.tar.gz
        deleted:    guo/rappdirs_0.3.1.tar.gz
        deleted:    guo/reticulate_1.18.tar.gz
        deleted:    guo/truncnorm_1.0-8.tar.gz
        deleted:    guo/guo.zip
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/dataAnalysis.pyc
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/dataDetection.pyc
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo.properties
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guoCoreMain.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guoFunc/__init__.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/addExpertKnowledge.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/batchAddExpertKnowledge.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/calculateVif.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/checkSampleNumber.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/clearExpertKnowledge.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/dataConvert.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/dataStat.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/delExpertKnowledge.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/factorGraph.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/factorRankingNonlinear.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/graphCorrMatrix.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/hybridNonlinearARD.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/impactAnalysis.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/importExpertKnowledge.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/guoBaseHandle.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/guoConsts.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/guoException.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/guoListener.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/predictValue.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/search.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/simulationNonlinear.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/guo/simulationOrdinalPython.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/inguoUtils/PropertiesUtil.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/inguoUtils/__init__.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/inguoUtils/inguoUtils.py
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/knowledgeBase.pyc
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/knowledgeConflict.pyc
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/knowledgeMgmt.pyc
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/nonlinearAnalysis.pyc
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/pruning_mixed_used.pyc
        deleted:    guo/guo/src/startInguo.sh
        deleted:    guo/lib/Pillow-8.2.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/decorator-4.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz
        deleted:    guo/lib/future-0.18.2.tar.gz
        deleted:    guo/lib/inguo_causal_effect-0.0.3-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/joblib-0.17.0-py3-none-any.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/kiwisolver-1.3.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/logging2-0.1.2.tar.gz
        deleted:    guo/lib/matplotlib-3.4.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/networkx-2.5.1-py3-none-any.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/numpy-1.20.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/pandas-1.1.4-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/patsy-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/progressbar2-3.53.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/pygam-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/pymongo-3.10.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/python_utils-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/pytz-2020.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/reportlab-3.5.34-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/savReaderWriter-3.4.2.tar.gz
        deleted:    guo/lib/scikit_learn-0.23.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/scipy-1.5.4-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/sklearn-0.0.tar.gz
        deleted:    guo/lib/statsmodels-0.12.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/stomp.py-6.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/threadpoolctl-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/tqdm-4.60.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
        deleted:    guo/lib/xgboost-1.0.1-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
        deleted:    guo/inguo-front/guo-front-0.26.1-c3.jar

[user@ip-172-24-30-17 docker]$
```

Comment: any suggestions how to resolve this conflicts.

Comment: Did you resolve this already with your most recent edit? If so, please put the content of that edit into an answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: No am still getting above in git status : On branch us-master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64.tar.gz
        new file:   gh_2.0.0_linux_amd64/LICENSE, Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    .gitignore
        modified:   analyze/Dockerfile
        modified:   guo-m/Dockerfile
        modified:   guo-m/guo-m/application.properties

Comment: Any suggestions, please

Comment: I'm unsure what your actual problem is here, can you not just stage all your changes and then commit? The status isnt showing where the problem in your files lie. 
From my understanding, you need to ensure that you resolve the conflictions per file before commiting. 
Are you familiar with git? Maybe try give this a read https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts

Comment: According to i tried to merge master branch from bitbucket of docker repostiory in US master branch in same docker repostiory am gettting above conflicts, also i added some git add suggested by git status in us master brnach , still  on github portal showing conflicts to resolve.